# Insert buyer's name into a PDF through Linux CLI?

Tags: linux, pdf, paypal, pdf-generation

I have a client who wants to sell PDF books with the buyer's name and timestamp embedded in the PDF so it would be visible on several pages through the PDF book. This would be purchased through PayPal. Is there Linux command line software to write a string into a PDF so that it is visible when viewed as a PDF document? Don't want to watermark the page, just a small section for it to print something like "Purchased by John Doe on MM/DD/YY'.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to take a look at the toolchain of commands Calibre uses when editing ebooks, of which PDF is one of the formats

Comment: Does it support Linux command line? Or is this a manual product to use. It looks manual, I'm looking for Linux CLI solution. Thanks!

Comment: Calibre is manual. It uses a toolchain.